# Vim: Jump to previous cursor position, NOT edit point

Tags: vim, gvim, macvim

I am trying to write a tiny macro to append a ; to the end of the current line (A;), then return to the cursor position from which I jumped before executing the macro.

C-o and C-i are not what I need, nor are '' and ``, which operate on edit points. 
Is there no way to do this without placing a marker?

Comment: Well, apparently it isn't edit points `` and '' are operating at, however their behaviour is unreliable. The result of tapping `` or '' after a jump ($, 3j, G etc) is VERY rarely the previous location. Although one might argue that I don't "get" it, I think this is unintuitive and hope someone knows a better approach.

Comment: No, the double-backtick is the right approach.

Comment: It rarely jumps to the previous location, though. Maybe because I don't know what is considered "jumps" and what is written into the jump history.. Unintuitive none the less.

Comment: The trick is to create the mark before you jump: m`A;<esc>``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are okay with making a tiny function instead of a tiny macro, I would propose the following:

```
function! AppendString(string)
  if getline('.') !~ a:string.'$'
    let original_cursor_position = getpos('.')
    exec("s/$/".a:string."/")
    call setpos('.', original_cursor_position)
  endif
endfunction
```

The cursor position is obtained using `getpos()` and is later recovered with `setpos()`.

This function could append any string you want. Also it checks if the line already has the desired string in the end, in which case it does nothing.

You may define keymaps that use this function that are useful for different languages:

```
" in ftplugin/cpp.vim
nnoremap <silent> <LocalLeader>; :call AppendString(";")<CR>
```

or

```
" in ftplugin/python.vim
nnoremap <silent> <LocalLeader>: :call AppendString(":")<CR>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use low-level `setpos()` instead of `:substitute` (which has other unwanted side effects such as adding the pattern to the search history), the cursor position will be kept automatically:

```
:nnoremap <silent> <leader>; :call setline('.', getline('.') . ';')<CR>
```

Comment: That's clever! These lower level functions are really broadening the horizon of my Vim config :)

Answer (score 2):

The behaviour of `` and what are considered as "jumps" are clearly explained in the doc.

From `:help jump-motions`:

> A "jump" is one of the following commands: "'", "`", "G", "/", "?", "n", "N", "%", "(", ")", "[[", "]]", "{", "}", ":s", ":tag", "L", "M", "H" and the commands that start editing a new file.  If you make the cursor "jump" with one of these commands, the position of the cursor before the jump is remembered.  You can return to that position with the "''" and "``" command, unless the line containing that position was changed or deleted.

`A` is obviously not in the list so "tick-tick-back", as Gary Bernhardt calls it, won't work "as is". It is still a good approach, though, but you must explicitly place the backtick mark *before* you do `A;`

```
nnoremap <key> m`A;<Esc>``
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up writing a tiny function, a less flexible but more compact version than what you just posted.

Keybind:

```
nnoremap <leader>; :call AppendSC()<CR>
```

Function:

```
fun! AppendSC()
  let pos = getpos('.')
  s/.*/&;/
  call setpos('.', pos)
endf
```

Comment: I'll mark yours as the accepted one though, since your solution solved my initial problem. :)

Comment: Apparently you can additionally squeeze the function definition in one line if compactness is your major concern :]